# System.TypeInitializationException in external code

Tags: c#, debugging

Just upgraded my PC to Windows 10 (from 8.1), and installed Visual Studio 2015 as well. When trying to debug a program I've been working on for a while, I immediately get an exception saying `An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`, and I am not getting a view of the code which throws it.

With that in mind and that the callstack only shows one thing which is `External Code` with the Language field blank, I suspect there is some .dll which isn't there, or is incompatible.

What I'm wondering is how I can find the piece of code or file which is giving me this problem, cause I am clueless as to what to do next..

Comment: Check the `InnerException` to see what's the actual issue.

Comment: @Rahul There usually is a button you can press to view the inner exception, but it isn't there!  [check this.](http://i.imgur.com/e7CaAd6.png) I don't know if I have to enable something or?

Comment: Use `copy exception details in clipboard`

Comment: @Rahul It says exactly the same thing as in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after about two hours of digging around the Internet for similar problems, I found that searching for static initializes probably would yield a solution to my problem, and with additional detective work I managed to find that a data-file in a static class couldn't be read because of securityprivileges in that specific folder, which in turn gave me this exception.